# jQuery - Calculate sum of input fields including fields added later

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, sum

I have a form to which you can add more input fields. All have the same class. Whenever an input field is changed I calculate the sum of all those input fields.

It works for all existing fields. As soon as I try it with a newly added field it doesn't work anymore.

I thought that I may have to use the "live" event. But can't figure out how.

This is my code:

```
$('.price_item').change(function() {
   var ntotal = 0;
   $('.price_item').each(function() {
      ntotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
   });
});
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your event handler on the document since you need this to handle elements that do not exist yet.

```
$(document).on('change', '.price_item', function() {
    var ntotal = 0;
    $('.price_item').each(function(){
        ntotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Adding a JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkgb2/)

Comment: Good to hear and no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) like,

```
$(document).on('change', '.price_item', function() {
    var ntotal = 0;
    $('.price_item').each(function(){
        ntotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/on/ should work for what you need:

```
$(document).on('change', '.price_item', handlePriceItemChange);
function handlePriceItemChange(){
  var ntotal = 0;
   $('.price_item').each(function(){
      ntotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.9 you can't use .live(), so you should use .on().

Try something like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
$(document).on('change', 'input', function(){

    var ntotal = 0;
    $('.price_item').each(function(){
        ntotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });

    console.log('sum: ' + ntotal);

    //adds new input for testing
    $(this).after('<input type="text" class="price_item" />');
});               
});
```